# Restore view phase takes around 10s instead of 20ms on development environment

Tags: performance, jsf

Our JSF application performance is very nice on our local environment. But when we pushed our application to development environment, the same application performance is very very slow. When I looked to development environment logs, I found that Restore View Phase is taking most of the time. It takes around 10-11 sec. Same Restore View Phase takes only 20ms on our local environment.

What could be the possible reason? Could it be code related or anything else?

Comment: Most straightforward cause would be that Facelet cache is disabled (as by default when javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE=Development), but still, 10s is really extreme. Which JSF impl/version are you using? (and it is exactly the same on both sides?)

Comment: We are using version JSF 2.0 and primefaces 5.1.9. I have the entry javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE=Development for my local environment, But do i need to put any corresponding entry also for my DEVELOPMENT environment?

Comment: "JSF 2.0" is just the specification version. I was specifically asking for the implementation name and its version. E.g. "Mojarra 2.2.11" or "MyFaces 2.2.8".

Comment: if i understood you correctly , we are using DeltaSpike JSF-Module Impl 1.0.0. I just used like below to know these info.                           Package jsfPackage = FacesContext.class.getPackage();
String implTitle = jsfPackage.getImplementationTitle();
String implVersion = jsfPackage.getImplementationVersion();
String implVendor = jsfPackage.getImplementationVendor();